# Is there a way to pass multiple 2D arrays to a function in C?

Tags: arrays, c, function, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

I'm implementing the resource allocation algorithm and in that I want computation of the safety sequence to occur in a function outside the main(). So am guessing that I need to pass the Need, Available and MAX matrix to the function.
I've surfed the internet and I can't find a way to pass multiple two-dimensional arrays to a function.
Is it even possible to do so?

Comment: "I'm implementing the resource allocation algorithm and in that I want computation of the safety sequence to occur in a function outside the main()"  I have no idea what this means. Is it relevant to the question? If so please clarify.

Comment: I don't see why you can't pass 2d arrays as normal parameters. You would, of course, have to specify the size too.

Comment: "I've surfed the internet and I can't find a way to pass multiple two-dimensional arrays to a function." Do you know how to pass more than one "simple" parameter (e.g. `int`s) to a function? For me your question is unclear because I get the impression that you think that only one paramter is possible...

Answer (score 2):

```
void function_accepting_2d_array (size_t x, size_t y, int arr [x][y]);

void function_accepting_2_2d_arrays (size_t x1, size_t y1, int arr1 [x1][y1],
                                     size_t x2, size_t y2, int arr2 [x2][y2]);

void function_accepting_n_2d_arrays (size_t n, size_t x, size_t y, int arr[n][x][y]);
```

Alternatively, in case you don't need to know how many arrays there are:

```
void function_accepting_n_2d_arrays (size_t x, size_t y, int arr[][x][y]);
```

Comment: The first is your guess how OP hands a single 2D array, isn't it? Because I think it is not an option to do what OP is asking about. Some prose explanation would improve the helpfulness of your answer I think.

Comment: @Yunnosch There's just no many ways to do it. The only other option is to drop VLA in favour for constant sizes. Then there are various more or less stupid ways to emulate 2D arrays either using a "mangled" one in the form of a 1D array, or a pointer-based look-up table with fragmented data, which is not a 2D array but something else. I'm assuming the OP knows what a 2D array is since they are asking about one.